# How to change the colorAccent color for particular activity or fragment android

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, background-color

How to change the color accent for particular activity or fragment. Also I want to change the edit text base line color when it is in focus mode android.
I am struck in this situation.
Thanks in advance

Comment: use this `android:backgroundTint="yourColor"`

Comment: Yes I used this one but it only show when edit text in normal. When edit text is activated the color becomes coloraccent color.